# Can a loop cause issues with assignment in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, concatenation

(This is related to a previous issue I had.)  In trying to assign values from one character array to another, I'm facing a weird problem where the correct values aren't being copied but only when I use a loop.  I commented out the loop and wrote out its iterations manually and it worked as I wanted it to.  What could be causing this issue?

> //Causes incorrect data transfer
>
> ```
>  for(int q=0; q<4; q++){
>
>
>    directory[q] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(temp[q])));
>
>    strcpy(directory[q],temp[q]);
>
>
>   }
> ```
>
> //But this works as it should
>
> ```
> directory[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(temp[0])));
>
> strcpy(directory[0], temp[0]);
>
> directory[1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(temp[1])));
>
> strcpy(directory[1], temp[1]);
>
> directory[2] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(temp[2])));
>
> strcpy(directory[2], temp[2]);
>
> directory[3] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(temp[3])));
>
> strcpy(directory[3], temp[3]);
> ```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 so you can remove the multiplication by it. As for this code, I see nothing wrong so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Please post code that exhibits the actual problem. By the way, read up on `strdup`.

Comment: No don't, `strdup` is pure evil.

Comment: I agree with seth - is this a copy-paste from your code, or did you wrote it in here again? if it's not a copy-paste, please copy your exact code.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: What OP does is pure evil as well, no?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis not as evil as `strdup`.

Comment: Ok, let me post the other part.

Comment: `strdup(); /*check success*/` is no more evil that `malloc(1 + strlen()); /*check malloc success*/ strcpy` as it comes down to exactly the same thing. Indeed it is less evil insofar as it relieves the programmer of the need to recall the `+1`. Leaving off the failure check is, of course, evil in either case.

Comment: @dmckee It is more evil because it hides the call to `malloc`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie You already have to remember several functions that return `alloc`ed memory. At least I do because I program in a unix environment, and there are a bunch of APIs that hand you `alloc`ed stuff. You just add it to the list.

Comment: @dmckee additionally with the advent of VLAs, it's wasteful to allocate something on the heap when you could do it on the stack. Then you don't have to deal with deallocation at all. I realise you can't do that in every case, but why add another function to the "list" when you can just use `malloc`/`strcpy`? Or even better, move to C++ and use `unique_ptr` </provocation> :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie Why use the function instead of writing two lines and having to put the test between them? Because `strdup` makes neater, more readable code.