# How to convert const char* to char* in C?

Tags: c, pointers, const-char

In my project there is a method which only returns a `const char*`, whereas I need a `char*` string, as the API doesn't accept `const char*`.

Any idea how to convert between `const char*` to `char*`?

Comment: Beware that the API might have been design this way with good reasons in mind.

Comment: @alk I'd said this below and this is the situation: The const char* is returned by an objective-C string method[NSString's to be more specific). This is a path of a file which got saved. Now there is another C library's api which will be parsing this file and it only takes char* strings as arguments. Even if i pass the const char* string, the parsing happens but i get a warning which i don't want to see.

Comment: As others pointed out: As you never know what the parser does (think of what `strtok()` does)  make a copy of the data returned and pass on the copy. `strdup()`and `free()` are your friends.

Comment: Can you tell us which functions they are and link to their documentation?

Comment: Good to read, we could convince you to not simply cast away a meaningful warning. However don't forget to `free()` what `strdup()` allocated!

Comment: And in C++ there is `const_cast<>()`

Comment: @alk sure... Right now I'm dealing with an API which has "those reasons" and they're "we didn't care if anyone 50+ years later will be using our code". Which is literally the only good reason I can think of, care to elaborate on what exactly what do you mean?  For reference, I'm looking at this function `int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);` and considering I'm using modern C++, my reason for abstracting it is "fuck your arcane bullshit reasons". Except it doesn't work as well as I expected it to, thanks to the fact that argv[], which nobody ever ever ever modifies, is not const.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To make sure you don't break stuff, make a copy of the returned string.

The function returning `const char*` expects this string will never be changed. Therefore things can/will break if your code or the API you pass it make a change after all.

Even worse, if a change is made, your program is likely to crash you in case the returned string was literal (e.g. `"hello I'm a literal string"`) because they are (often) stored in memory that can't be written to.

You could use `strdup()` for this, but read the [small print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984948/why-is-strdup-considered-to-be-evil). Or you can of course create your own version if it's not there on your platform.

Comment: Necro for a response to the question can't you change your code: APIs often require string, char* or const char*, and yeah in theory you could change the entire API, but it's good information to know how to quickly convert it

Comment: @Skathix You're right, APIs can't often be changed (I think wrote that in error). Removed that part of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 80):

First of all you should do such things only if it is really necessary - e.g. to use some old-style API with `char*` arguments which are not modified. If an API function modifies the string which was const originally, then this is unspecified behaviour, very likely crash.

Use cast:

```
(char*)const_char_ptr
```

Comment: I think this answer as it is encourages too much a dangerous practice.  It could be improved by making the warnings about undefined behaviour clearer and stronger. At the moment I think many readers will just read the first 2 lines and not notice the important warnings.

Comment: Now warnings are first and the answer later.

Comment: Or at least use const_cast<char*> so the compiler knows too.

Comment: @MultiMat No such thing as const_cast in C.

Comment: My C++ is rusty but wouldnt this cause issues, when it goes out of scope?

Comment: @Rika Your comment is not very clear and the discussion is about C not C++. Anyway the answer to question whether casting away constness may introduce problems with scope and lifetime is: no it does not introduce such problems.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the `strdup` function which has the following prototype

```
char *strdup(const char *s1);
```

Example of use:

```
#include <string.h>

char * my_str = strdup("My string literal!");
char * my_other_str = strdup(some_const_str);
```

or strcpy/strncpy to your buffer

or rewrite your functions to use `const char *` as parameter instead of `char *` where possible so you can preserve the `const`

Comment: strdup is a non standard implemantation.
So you shouldn't be sure he "can use it"

Comment: Implementing a missing `strdup()` is a matter of 15 minutes.

Comment: @alk of course. But as the OP is catching such a problem and is asking for a solution, it is posibbly not a solution for him "implementing strdup by your self" ya know?

Comment: @Zaibis: `if (constptr) {char * p = calloc(strlen(constptr)+1, sizeof(*constptr)); if (!p) fail(); strcpy(p, constptr); my_nonconstptr_func(p); free(p);}`

Comment: @alk well, now we have the implementation. Doesn't change anything on my statement. ;)

Answer (score 7):

A `const` to a pointer indicates a "read-only" memory location. Whereas the ones without `const` are a read-write memory areas. So, you "cannot" convert a `const`(read-only location) to a normal(read-write) location.

The alternate is to copy the data to a different read-write location and pass this pointer to the required function. You may use `strdup()` to perform this action.

Comment: Exactly. const is specified to say that the value remains constant and cannot be further modified.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a `const char*` to `char*` you could create a function like this :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* unconstchar(const char* s) {
    if(!s)
      return NULL;
    int i;
    char* res = NULL;
    res = (char*) malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    if(!res){
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation Failed! Exiting...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else{
        for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            res[i] = s[i];
        }
        res[i] = '\0';
        return res;
    }
}

int main() {
    const char* s = "this is bikash";
    char* p = unconstchar(s);
    printf("%s",p);
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: In this code uninitialized variable `res` is used. This code `res[i] = s[i]` is undefined behavior, most likely crash.

Comment: Updated Code: Added check for NULL and possibly resolved undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it by doing `(char *)Identifier_Of_Const_char`

But as there is probabbly a reason that the api doesn't accept `const cahr *`,
you should do this only, if you are sure, the function doesn't try to assign any value in range of your `const char*` which you casted to a non const one.

Comment: the const char* is returned by an objective-C string method[NSString's to be more specific). This is a path of a file which got saved. Now there is another C library's api which will be parsing this file and it only takes char* strings as arguments. Even if i pass the const char* string, the parsing happens but i get a warning which i don't want to see.

Comment: @Morpheus Anyway, you can't be sure as long you didn't analyze the source by your self.

Answer (score -1):

For example, you could write this way:

```
const char* a = "art.bin";
char* b = new char[sizeof(a)];
strcpy(b, a);
```

Comment: C doesn't have a `new` operator. Please don't use C++ to answer C questions. Additionally, answers are more useful when they explain things rather than just provide a snippet of code.