# Invalid Next Size (fast) when I try to free a string

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, crash

when I cannot figure out the issue with my code. The goal of the program is to read words from a text file and add them to a linked list. When I run this:

```
static char *make_string(char buffer[], int length) {
      char *str = (char *)(malloc(length+1));
      memcpy(str, buffer, length);
      str[length + 1] = '\0';
      return str;
    }

char *words_next_word() {
  char buf[MAXBUF] = {0};

  int character = getchar();
  int index = 0;
  static int count = 0;
  printf("it is the %d word \n", count);
  count++;

  while(isalnum(character) == 0){
    character = getchar();
  }

  while(character != EOF && isalnum(character) != 0){
    buf[index] = character;
    index++;
    character = getchar();
  }

  return make_string(buf, index);
}
```

After getting the word from the text file, I add it to a linked list. After adding the word, I free the string. The first 138 words are read and freed without issue. For some reason, the program crashes when trying to read the 138'th word, but I don't know why.

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `str[length]` just before `return str;`?

Comment: `str[length + 1] = '\0';` out-of-bounds write, undefined behavior.

Comment: Is there any reason why this code would work for the first 137 words and not the 138th?

Comment: @BobFlanders Undefined Behavior is not required to be consistent. It is *undefined*.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know that undefined behavior was inconsistent (though I should have figured).

Comment: "For some reason, the program crashes when trying to read the 138'th word," --> Future tip: post relevant information like definition of `MAXBUF`, input data used, output seen, output expected and and enough code so others may compile and replicate the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first 138 words are read and freed without issue.

Not really.  The problem exists even in the first `make_string()` call.

---

Code is attempting to duplicate the string yet has a off-by-one error.

```
static char *make_string(char buffer[], int length) {
      char *str = (char *)(malloc(length+1));  // size good
      memcpy(str, buffer, length);             // copy OK
      str[length + 1] = '\0';     // null character assigned in wrong place, 1 too far out
      return str;
    }
```

Assigning data in the wrong place (assigning out of bounds [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913357/invalid-next-size-fast-when-i-try-to-free-a-string/42913760#comment72925949_42913357)) and not defining the value of `str[length]` with a null character (and later using it) results in *undefined behavior*.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39694254/2410359) is a `strdup()` function, yet I suggest trying to code repair your `make_string()` before reviewing.

---

The below code does not limit writing to `buf[]`

```
while(character != EOF && isalnum(character) != 0){
    if (index + 1 >= MAXBUF) {
      puts("Too long");
      return NULL; // or some other error handling
    }
    buf[index] = character;
```