# C - How to get string from user when using typedef?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, fgets

I have the following typedef in my code:

```
typedef char * string;
```

And I need to have the user input a string so that I can then parse it and use the contents later. If I am just declaring a string with this definition it works, like this:

```
string bob = "My name is bob!;
printf("%s\n", bob);
```

What should I use to get user input when using this, scanf() and fgets()
both give me *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* errors when I try to use them.

This is for school, which is why I need to use the typedef this way.

Comment: The problem is not your typedef; you can use it as if you wrote `char *`. The problem is the target: When initializing `bob` with a string literal, it usually resides in non-writeable memory, hence the segfault (technically, it's UB). Try to initialize it with `malloc()`

Comment: string literals are in read only memory. You can't change them. So can't use in scanf either. Use `char str[MAXSIZE]` or `char *str =malloc(sizeof (char) *MAXSIZE)`. Trying to modify a readonly memory is undefined behavior. Also with the `malloc` when you allocate..check for the return value and also dont forget to `free` them. In this case, as you have said `typedef has problem`...no it has not. `typedef` should be used in case of complicated types that you want to use...here it loses readability because of `typedef`-ing `char*`. Segfaults-caused by program trying to read/write illegal memory

Comment: It is not a good idea in C to [`typedef` a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: @coderredoc Detail: "string literals are in read only memory" is almost right and a useful axiom for a learner. Yet there is no read-only memory requirement in C.  Writing to a  _string literal_  might "work", it might not.  After all it is is UB.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers everybody, they helped a lot!

Comment: @WeatherVane In [select cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750341/2410359) of [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), `typedef` a pointer is good.  Even though I do not favor  `typedef char * string;`, for learners, it is (unfortunately) common.

Comment: @chux once, I too used  to `typedef` pointers because they made the code easier to write ~ actually compile! They made the syntax easier. But later I understood that, when familiar with the syntax, it makes the code *harder* to understand. This comment is really to OP.

Answer (score 0):

you can `typedef` a `pointer variable` but must be taken care while using or accessing that `typedefed pointer variable` because normally you won't see `*` symbol in `declaration` and `definition` may be somewhere else and you may treat as a normal variable.

If you want to take input for pointer variable from runtime or from file first you should allocate the memory.

```
int main()
    {
            typedef char * string;// now string also a char pointer
            string bob;// bob is pointer variable
            printf("enter the string\n");
            scanf("%s",bob);//bob is uninitialized pointer .. u can't put any data
            printf("%s\n", bob);
          //once job is done free dynamically allocated memory using free function 
    }
```

Above code will cause segmentation fault,So allocate the memory dynamically first.

```
        string bob;
        bob = malloc(SIZE);//how much memory you want , mention in SIZE variable.
        printf("enter the string\n");
        scanf("%s",bob);
        printf("%s\n", bob);
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",bob);` will not successfully scan in text like `"My name is bob!"` to `bob`.

Comment: For scanning a string with spaces instead of scanf we should use scanf("%[^\n]",bob)

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]",bob)` fails when 1) the leading character read is `'\n'` 2) It leaves the `'\n'` in `stdin` for later I/O rather than consume it 3) it does not prevent reading too much into `bob`.  `fgets()` is better.

Comment: Agree with @chux  .. Fgets is better option. Use like fgets(bob,size,stdin)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to set your starting value.
Assume you have `char * a;`
`a` has an undefined value, maybe pointing to an unauthorized area. You can not write in there.
What should you do? If you must use `typedef char * string;` , you have to write it on:
1) Dynamic heap, 2) on a buffer at the stack.

1) Use `malloc` - a function which has to be included from `stdlib.h`, and allocates memory at the Dynamic heap. The function returns a pointer to the start of the memory allocated. 
Don't forget after using it to free the allocated memory to avoid leak, by `free()` function.

2) Declaring a foretold array size of chars, and give it's address to your variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MY_SIZE 50
typedef char * string;

int main() {
    string s;

    // 1)
    s = malloc(MY_SIZE);
    // some code
    free(s);

    // 2)
    char buf[MY_SIZE];
    s = buf;

    return 0;
}
```

You have to practice both ways.
Hope that I've helped!

Comment: `s = &buf;` s/b `s = buf;`.  `s = &buf;` will usually "work" too, but it is assigning the wrong type (pointer to array 50 of char) to a `char *`

Answer (score 0):

> How to get string from user when using typedef? (`typedef char * string;`)

`string bob` needs to be assigned a value, a memory location is which to store the data read.

```
#define N 80 

// local array
char buf[N];
string bob = buf;
fgets(bob, N, stdin); 

// or malloc
string bob = malloc(N);
if (bob == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory(); 
fgets(bob, N, stdin);
```

Now trim the potential `'\n'`

```
bob[strcspn(bob, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Print result

```
printf("<%s>\n", bob);
```

> ... and use the contents later.

This implies code should use a right-sized memory allocation for use well passed this input code.    `strdup()` is not in the standard C library, but very common. 
 [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694197/when-is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-strdup-vs-malloc-strcpy/39694254#39694254).

```
 // local array approach
 bob = strdup(bob);
 // Now bob points to allocated memory

 // malloc approach
 // re-size to be efficient
 void *t = realloc(bob, strlen(bob) + 1);
 if (t) {
   bob = t;
 }
 // Detail: A realloc to a smaller amount of memory rarely ever fails.
 // If it did fail, just continue with old pointer.
```

If `bob` points to allocated memory, clean up when done with `bob`.

```
free(bob);
```

---

Only use `scanf()` if required and you can't drop the class or get employment elsewhere.