# How to get line from stdin and split it to tokens?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write RPN calculator, but I've been struggling with getting arguments from user. What I want to do is: take whole line, split it to tokens and put it to array. I have something like below, but it works only once. On the second while-loop performing *line* is taken, but `arr==NULL`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_str 100

char* getLine(){
  char* line = malloc(MAX_str*sizeof(char*));
  return fgets(line, MAX_str,stdin);
}

char** toArray(char* line){
  int i=0;
  char** array= malloc(MAX_str*sizeof(char*));
  array[i] = strtok(line," \t");
  while(array[i]!=NULL){
    array[++i] = strtok(NULL,"");
  }
  return array;
}

int main(){
  char* linia;
  char** arr;
  int i=0,end=0;

  while(!end){
    linia=getLine();
    arr = toArray(linia);
    while(arr[i]!=NULL){
      printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
      i++;
    }
  free(linia);
  free(arr);
  }
}
```

Secondly, `strtok` splits only on two tokens, for example

```
>1 2 3
```

gives:

```
>1
>2 3
```

Comment: Besides the big mess the code creates allocation to much (`sizeof(char*)`), to few (`sizeof(line)`), and missing the deallocate, you want to tell *each* call to `strdup()` to do the same, namely to tokenise by `" \t"`.

Comment: moorzyn, Curious: Why does code use `sizeof(line)` in `char** array =  malloc(MAX_str*sizeof(line));`?

Comment: Hint: `""` in `array[++i] = strtok(NULL,"");` is a very small token list.

Comment: @allk Re: [to few (sizeof(line))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153911/how-to-get-line-from-stdin-and-split-it-to-tokens-c#comment83286792_48153911).  this looks unusual, yet `malloc(MAX_str*sizeof(line));` does not appear too few.  Your thoughts?

Comment: Well, I am just starting learning C, so this is why it look so bad.

@chux I meant to be `char*` there, not `line`. I don't know why I put it there. I have edited the code.

Comment: @moorzyn Tip: instead of `char** array= malloc(MAX_str*sizeof(char*));` and hope the correct type was used, code `char** array= malloc(MAX_str*sizeof *array);` and remove all doubt.  Easier to code, review and maintain.  See this works even if `array` was declared earlier elsewhere and code was doing `array= malloc(MAX_str * sizeof *array);`

Comment: Do not updated your question with an answer.  You can post your own answer to the question if you like. Post rolled back

Answer (score 0):

Code's primary problem is using an empty token string for subsequent calls of `strtok()`.  Add as needed, characters to the 2nd token list

```
// array[++i] = strtok(NULL,"");
array[++i] = strtok(NULL," \t\n");
```

---

Improvement idea for `getLine()`: read and then allocate.

```
char* getLine(){
  char buf[MAX_str];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return strdup(buf);
}
```

`strdup()` is common, although not in the C standard.  [Code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39694254/2410359).

Answer (score 0):

Well, being stupid costs time... I have forgotten to reset `i` after while-loop in `main()`...

Is this code better? I want `arr`  to be table of `char` pointers in amount of `MAX_str`. Is it declared well? With `malloc` would it be initialized like in answers above? To prevent `array` overflow I would compare `i` and value of `MAX_str`. Would it be ok?

```
#define MAX_str 100

char* getLine(){
  char buf[MAX_str];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return strdup(buf);
}

int toArray(char* line, char* array[MAX_str]){
  int i=0;
  array[i] = strtok(line," \t\n");
  while(array[i]!=NULL){
    array[++i] = strtok(NULL," \t\n");
  }
  return i;
}

int main(){
  char* linia;
  char* arr[MAX_str];
  int i=0,end=0;

  while(!end){
    linia=getLine();
    assert(linia!=NULL);

    toArray(linia,arr);
    assert(arr!=NULL);

    while(arr[i]!=NULL){
      printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```