# Realloc returns invalid pointer when char array is passed into another function

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I have a short snippet where I am passing a char array into another function and changing the size in memory.

```
// in main
char *str = argv[1];
find(&str);

void func(char **str){
  // some code
  *str = realloc(*str, 10+1);
}
```

This gives the error

```
realloc(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What did I do wrong here? In order to change the value of `str` in another function, I am using a double pointer.

Comment: You can only reallocate an array that was allocated with `malloc`. `argv[1]` is not dynamically allocated.

Comment: @Barmar being pedantic, it might be dynamically allocated, but not in a way that it can be `realloc()`ed, or `argv[]` might be in read-only memory, etc, etc.

Comment: @KenY-N It's not specified to be dynamically allocated, so you can't assume it is. So as far as being able to call realloc, it should be considered not dynamically allocated.

Comment: Note on `realloc` (not your primary issue, but...). Do NOT `realloc` to the original pointer, e.g. don't do `*str = realloc(*str, 10+1);` instead, use a temporary pointer, e.g. `void *tmp = realloc(*str, 10+1);`, then validate the reallocation `if (tmp == NULL) { /* handle error - return or exit */ }; *str = tmp;` That way when `realloc` fails, you don't overwrite your original pointer with `NULL` losing the address to the prior allocated block creating a memory leak.

Comment: @KenY-N: it can't be in read-only memory. Sect 5.1.2.2.1; "The parameters **argc** and **argv** and the strings pointed to by the **argv** array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination."

Answer (score 3):

> What did I do wrong here?

`*str` in `realloc(*str, 10+1)` was not allocated by this process. [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312326/realloc-returns-invalid-pointer-when-char-array-is-passed-into-another-function/60312438#comment106687324_60312326)

Your code could have used the below or equivalent to allocate its own copy to later reallocate it.  As `strdup()` is not in C STL as of C17, [a sample implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39694254/2410359).

```
char *str = strdup(argv[1]);
```

Comment: `strdup` is not in ISO C

Comment: Apparently it [will be in C20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup).

Comment: @M.M Post amended to include that.