# How to store a string in a multidimensional array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, multidimensional-array

I'm new at C and I'm trying to do an exercise which asks to insert some strings and then store them. First it requests a multidimensional array where we have for every row of the array a string, and then as an array of pointers. 
Here's the code for the first part. I don't know how to store into an array some strings that are not already written.

For the second one I have no idea since I've never done exercises with pointers before.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int n; //number of strings
int x; //number of characters per string

    printf("How many strings do you want to insert?");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if ((n >= 1) && (n <= 20)){
        printf("How many characters per string?");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        char str[x];

            if (x <= 10){
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                    printf("Insert a string:");
                    scanf("%s", str);
                    for(int j = 0; j < x; j++){
                        char arr[j];
                        arr[j] = str[x];
                        printf("%s", arr);
                    }
        }
            }
            else {
                printf("Error:the number of characters must be < 10");
            }
    }
    else {
        printf("Error: the number must be < 20");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid you'll need to go back to your favorite book/tutorial and read a bit about how to declare and use arrays.

Comment: Yes, do some simpler things with pointers before in order to get familiar with the concept of pointers.

Comment: Hints: in C, `char str[5];` declares an array of 5 characters. `char str[x];` would be what is called a Variable Length Array, this is only supported by some versions of the C standard and probably not what you should use as a beginner (even if it might happen to work). You should be careful not to create an array with size zero, accessing that would be Undefined Behavior (you do this at `char arr[j];`).

Comment: I agree. I noticed a couple of mistakes and I was writing an answer listing them. Then I came to the part in which you copy the string to your array... but there's not any 2-D array..

Answer (score 2):

> ... requests a multidimensional array where we have for every row of the array a string, and then as an array of pointers.

After getting the qualified number of strings, allocate an array of pointers to `char`.

```
if ((n >= 1) && (n <= 20)){
  char **string_list = calloc(n, sizeof *string_list);
  assert(string_list);  // or other error checking
```

(Notice no type in `= calloc(n, sizeof *string_list);`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.)

Read the strings in a working temp buffer.  As "How many characters per string?" likely means the number of characters *not* including the *null character*, our `str[]` needs a +1 in size.

```
        // char str[x]; // too small
        char str[x+1];
```

Yet we know `x <= 10` and can use a fixed buffer size and limit input length

```
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        char str[10+1];
        printf("Insert a string:");
        scanf("%10s", str);  // Notice the 10 - a width limit

        // TBD check if scanf() returned 1 and if str is longer than x
```

Now allocate a copy of the `str`

```
        string_list[j] = strdup(str);
        assert(string_list[j]);  // or other error checking
      }
```

Later, when done with `string_list[]`, [clean-up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1b4gSs0KhIU) and free allocations.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  free(string_list[i]);
}
free(string_list);
```

---

What is weak about this:

It uses `scanf()` rather than `fgets()` and then parses, has minimal error checking, does not take in *strings* with spaces, does not handle over-long input, [`strdup()` is not standard -yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694197/when-is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-strdup-vs-malloc-strcpy/39694254#39694254), etc.

So the above is a baby step.  Better code would handle the weak issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is necessary to usethe function  `calloc`? Is there no other way?

Comment: @Schiele There are other ways.  What is the concern about `calloc()` and what restrictions are there that prevent using `calloc()`?

Comment: It's just that this is an exercise which is not supposed to use this function (according to the exercise text)

Comment: Then use `char **string_list = malloc(sizeof *string_list * n); memset(string_list, 0, sizeof *string_list * n);`

Comment: The problem is that I can not use anything related to dynamic memory allocation

Comment: @Schiele With c99, after getting `x,n` use [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) `string_list[n][x+1];`