# Why does free() cause a program crash in this code?

Tags: c, memory-management, crash, free

I've already searched for an answer to this, but so far haven't come up with anything that answers the specific question, so asking here.

I have some C code that dynamically allocates space for a string and copies in the contents of a buffer that's sat in a local variable.  This dynamically allocated string is then stored in a struct and used elsewhere in the program.

Now, when I'm done with the struct, I'm trying to be a good citizen and deallocate the string, however when I do so, without fail, the program crashes.  As far as I can tell, I'm passing in the correct pointer to free(), and if I omit the call to free() then I've confirmed that I'm leaking memory, so what am I doing wrong?

Here's the gist of the code.

```
typedef struct Token {
    size_t length;
    const char* lexeme;

    // Other members
} Token;

// Original string is stored in a stack allocated static buffer:
static char buffer[1024];

// ... stuff here to fill buffer

// Then we generate the dynamic copy of the buffer contents
char* formattedMessage = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer));

// Token is dynamically allocated as needed:
Token* token = realloc(NULL, sizeof(Token));
token->lexeme = strcpy(formattedMessage, buffer);
token->length = strlen(formattedMessage);

// ... Then we do other stuff (which all works, the message is stored in the struct and all is well)

// When we're done we call:
token->lexeme = free((void*)(token->lexeme));

// Which is where the program crashes.
```

Note that in the actual code, I *do* test that token->lexeme is a valid pointer to a string and checking the memory dump as I'm tracing through shows that the address being passed into free() is the correct address for the string.

Tearing my hair out here.

Comment: You corrupted memory. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: `char* formattedMessage = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer));` is wrong. `strlen` returns the number of non-null characters in the string. The memory requirement is one more, for the null terminator. Then `strcpy(formattedMessage, buffer);` writes outside the allocated memory. Your program may have additional bugs.

Comment: Kind of an aside: Using `realloc()` to just allocate memory is weird and confusing. Using the return value from `strcpy()` is also very unusual. Keep your code as simple as you can.

Comment: You cannot do that: `token->lexeme = strcpy(formattedMessage, buffer);` as `token->lexeme` ist not pointing to valid memory. Note that the previous line allocated memory for a `struct Token` but it **does not** allocate memory for the pointers inside the struct.

Comment: @pmacfarlane oh yes, you're right. I consider that bad style, very easy to miss.

Comment: You `realloc` on a existing pointer variable `Token` - that's not good practice, `realloc` into a temporary pointer variable, check if its legitimate pointer, then check the contents to make sure they are valid, if it is `NULL` do not assign it back  to the original pointer variable `Token`.

Comment: @t0mm13b OP has `Token* token = realloc(NULL, sizeof(Token));`.  `token` has no previous value as this is the _definition_ of `token`.  For a re-allocation, your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640853/why-does-free-cause-a-program-crash-in-this-code/76641744#comment135124978_76640853) makes sense, yet this is a first time allocation for `token` - even though is calls `realloc()`.

Comment: Thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, using `realloc(NULL, ...)` is, not the right way to say this, "unusual" vs using `malloc(...)` unless there's a specific reason, despite the behaviour of `realloc(NULL,...)` is equivalent to `malloc(...)` - a case of overloading `realloc` - too many ways to "skin a cat"

Comment: @t0mm13b Since good questions oblige a user to take their problem code and filter down to a [mcve], things like weird `realloc(NULL, ...)` vs. common `malloc()` are excusable.  IMHO, the only folks who make great questions already know the answer.  (like teachers and lawyers)

Comment: OP: Why are you doing this `token->lexeme = free((void*)(token->lexeme));`  ? Member of the `Token`, `lexeme` is a `const char *` , why did you cast it to a `void *`? I would start there if I were you and fix this and debug it on that line.

Comment: @t0mm13b: The cast to void* is simply to avoid compiler warnings ... it'll work without but will complain that free expects void* as it's parameter.

Comment: @pmacfarlane:  The use of realloc is due to all allocations being performed by a separate function that handles initial allocation _and_ resizing of existing memory, hence the use of realloc throughout.  It looks a little odd here, because I've simply condensed the code down to the bare minimum.  (same as with my comment elsewhere about the line `token->lexeme = free((void*)(token->lexeme))` not working - that's an error I've introduced inadvertently in this boiled down code - in the actual code, the free() call is made via a function that returns NULL after the free takes place.

Comment: @MarkEdwards " it'll work without but will complain that free expects void* as it's parameter. " --> That hints you are not using a C compiler.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica gcc bundled with MinGW w64 9.0, although to be clear, the complainant is my IDE (CLion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy(a, b)` needs `a` to point to memory of at least size `strlen(b) + 1`.
`realloc(NULL, sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer))` allocates one less than needed.

`free()` does not return anything.  I would not expect `token->lexeme = free((void*)(token->lexeme));` to even compile.

---

Easy enough to fix, yet with the new C23 making `strdup()` part of the standard library, consider using that to allcate and copy a *string* - or [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74945120/2410359).

```
// Unnecessary casts removed

char* formattedMessage = strdup(buffer);
if (formattedMessage == NULL) {
  Handle_OutOfMemeory(); // TBD code
}

Token* token = realloc(NULL, sizeof token[0]);
if (token == NULL) {
  Handle_OutOfMemeory(); // TBD code
}
token->lexeme = formattedMessage;
token->length = strlen(formattedMessage);


// ... Then we do other stuff 

// When we're done we call:
free(token->lexeme)
free(token);
```

---

Style: `malloc(size);` is much more common than `realloc(NULL, size);`.

Comment: Sorry, the `token->lexeme = free((void*)(token->lexeme));` line is a result of my condensing the code down to bare minimum.  In reality, the call to free() is actually performed in a separate function that returns NULL after the free is done.

Comment: Ah, this was it ... an off-by-one error.  Allocating the extra character for the null terminator in the string was indeed the issue.  Obvious now I look at it with a fresh pair of eyes ... yesterday, I'd been looking at it for so long I think I'd gone code blind.